# How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Provider when trying to use OWL API

Tags: java

I've an ontology file and i'm working with OWL-API. I should retrieve for my class (#Doc) her **individuals** and **theirs Object Properties**
actually i tried two ways to get the individuals, but i get always this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Provider

(i think it mean that the compiler can not find my class !)

Comment: any help please !

Comment: This looks like you're missing some dependency, because what is not found is `javax.inject.Provider`. It'll be good if you share your Maven POM (`pom.xml`) file, too.

Comment: Can you please provide a full stacktrace?

Comment: Also please see the following StackOverflow questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822568/noclassdeffounderror-javax-inject-provider-and-classnotfoundexception-javax-in and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459428/getting-error-in-executing-owl-api

Comment: @EmreSevinç i do not have a clear idea about Maven, but i think that there is two way to use OWL api , i'm not working with '' Maven dependency '' but i'm using the jar file of owl-api in my project with Netbeans

Comment: @MojoJojo sorry but i do not know how to get it & i thought also that my problem is linked with parameters !

Comment: can you upload your code to github?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you either learn a bit of Maven (it'll be very helpful for your future Java projects), and add the following to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or, put  all of the JAR files  in the application classpath. (After all, this is what the [official documentation suggests](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation)).

But I highly advise that you with the first option, that is, learning just a bit of Maven. You'll spend less than a day, but in the end it'll save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: If you found my explanations useful, can you please `accept` what I write above as an answer, so that this question is resolved?

Comment: but when i will finish this step i fear that maybe i'll ask again another question linked with Object properties 'as i said in my main question' if it does not matter i'll accept

Comment: According to StackOverflow best practices and guidelines, it is better to ask this as a separate question because the question you asked above is more about Java and Java project building and configuration in general; not directly related to OWL and semantic web in particular.

Comment: I should change the wording of the official documentation. A dependency management system - be it Maven or anything else - is always the best option.